# Is this a frequency domain plot for audio?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, frequency, signal-processing

I have a program "spectrum" that draws an chart for an audio file (a short `.wav` with an human voice recorded on it).

I believe it is a frequency domain chart.

The problem is, when I play the audio, for each given second of playback there is a separate chart (here are 3 print screens from the program window at different times):
[image]

**Shouldn't it be just one frequency(time) chart?** Instead of **X something(time)** charts, where X is the number of time samples (what is that **"something"** on Y axis here?).

The code that generates the plot uses **FFT** (I guess). It comes from [Bass audio library](http://www.un4seen.com/):

```
void update(...){

...
float fft[1024];
BASS_ChannelGetData(chan, fft, BASS_DATA_FFT2048); // get the FFT data

for (x = 0; x<SPECWIDTH / 2; x++) {
    y = sqrt(fft[x + 1]) * 3 * SPECHEIGHT - 4; // sqrt makes low values more visible
    //y = fft[x + 1] * 10 * SPECHEIGHT; // linear scale (alternative)
    if (y>SPECHEIGHT) y = SPECHEIGHT; // cap it
        if (x && (y1 = (y + y1) / 2)) // interpolate from previous to make the display smoother
            while (--y1 >= 0) specbuf[y1*SPECWIDTH + x * 2 - 1] = y1 + 1;
    y1 = y;
    while (--y >= 0) specbuf[y*SPECWIDTH + x * 2] = y + 1; // draw level
}
}
```

I am very much a beginner in the field of the audio processing, **please take that into account**.

Comment: Might [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) be better suited for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting the output of a specific program.

Comment: @lemon why do people say "FFT" when they mean discrete Fourier transform? It's like saying "Farrari" when you mean "car".

Comment: @DanielSank I agree that it's a bad habit. Although in practice it usually *is* an FFT implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is the (square root of) amplitude versus frequency. It presumably breaks the audio into short intervals and then DFT's each interval individually.

The DFT of the entire sound would not be very insightful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and complex answer, as well as for the friendly attitude (that many people here do not share towards the beginners).